# Python restful services

Tags: python, soapui, restful-url

I'm using python to get a query from url

```
>>import requests

>>url='http://mylocalsite:8080/services/GetClean'

>>qr={'GetCleanRequest':{'mapping':'soap_addr', 'data':['1','Some town,some >>place']}}

>>head = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'UTF-8'}

>>ret = requests.get(url,headers=head,params=qr)

>>ret.status_code

>>print(ret.status_code)
```

But I get 404 error no matter what.

However if I use SoapUi that works just fine.
with

```
Endpoint=http://mylocalsite:8080

Resource=/services/GetClean

Parameters=?query={'GetCleanRequest':{'mapping':'soap_addr', 'data':['1','Some town,some place']}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you noticed that the query is different between the soap and rest? `'data':['1','Some town,some >>place']` vs `'data':['1','Some town,some place']`

Comment: An error while formating

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the get method to post.

```
ret = requests.post(url,headers=head,data=qr)
```

Comment: Why is it supposed to be a post method?

Comment: Didn't work with the post method. Still 404. In SoapUI - I used GET method.